# Redirect an already rewritten URL (that points to new underlying file)

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Replacing an old system with a new one which requires new files to be created and new URLs as well

However it's important that the old URLs redirect to the new ones

For now I am testing locally and have two simple files set up, `item.php` and `item-newpage.php`

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)-([a-zA-Z]+)-item/$ /item.php?size=$1&color=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)-([a-zA-Z]+)-item-newpage/$ /item-newpage.php?size=$1&color=$2
RedirectMatch 301 ^([a-zA-Z]+)-([a-zA-Z]+)-item/$ ^$1-$2-item-newpage/$ [R=301,L]
```

Also tried this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)-([a-zA-Z]+)-item/$ /item.php?size=$1&color=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)-([a-zA-Z]+)-item-newpage/$ /item-newpage.php?size=$1&color=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)-([a-zA-Z]+)-item/$ ^$1-$2-item-newpage/$ [R=301,L]
```

But no redirecting is taking place yet

Also, I'd really like to remove the references to the old files in my .htaccess file (i.e. line 2) and delete them from the server if possible

@anubhava, to boil it down to the desired outcome:

`www.mysite.com/small-blue-item/`

should 301 redirect to

`www.mysite.com/small-blue-item-newpage/`

Remembering that `/small-blue-item-newpage/` is powered by a new file now

Comment: What are some example URLs that you want to remove?

Comment: Hi, I provided an example :)

Comment: ok I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)-([a-zA-Z]+)-item/?$ /$1-$2-item-newpage/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)-([a-zA-Z]+)-item-newpage/$ /item-newpage.php?size=$1&color=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hi, this is very close; thank You. This is sending me to `arge-blue-item-newpage/$` with a dollar sign at the end of the URL (and the page isn't loading). If I manually delete the $ at the end of the url in the address bar the page loads. Don't know how to change the code to stop this extra $ from being put in the URL

Comment: PS - what does the question mark do on line two: `...item/?$`?

Comment: Corrected trailing `$` issues. `/?$` makes trailing `/` optional in the URI. Try it now